# How to use Range().Rows.count on another file in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the number of rows in another file to save it in a variable to use it later.
I am getting an error 1004 on the line `cpt2 = wbEmployees.Worksheets(1).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` in the below code.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub getData()
    Dim pathEmployees As String
    pathEmployees = openEmployees
If pathEmployees <> "" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim wbEmployees As Workbook
        Dim cpt1, cpt2, x As Integer
        Set wbEmployees = GetObject(pathEmployees)
        cpt1 = Range("E1", Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        cpt2 = wbEmployees.Worksheets(1).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        MsgBox (cpt1)
        MsgBox (cpt2)
End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function openEmployees() As String
    Dim dialogBoxEmployees As FileDialog
    Set dialogBoxEmployees = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With dialogBoxEmployees
        .Title = "Employees File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            openEmployees = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

I don't get it, why it do not work, `cpt1` is fine as I stay in the the same file, so it means there is an error when I try to call the path of that other file. However I am sure `pathEmployees` and `wbEmployees` are correctly defined.

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: Try using `cpt2 = wbEmployees.Worksheets(1).Range("A1", wbEmployees.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`. Otherwise, not fully qualifying the second part of the range, VBA tries using the `ActiveSheet` range and it raises the error... But, are there empty rows in that range? Otherwise, you should return the last cell, which means the number of rows, too: ``cpt2 = wbEmployees.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`. Do you need to count **up to the next empty row**?

Comment: I tried to use `cpt2 = wbEmployees.Worksheets(1).Range("A1", wbEmployees.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` but not working too.

Comment: In the column **A** there is user ID. No empty cell from the first one to the last one.

Comment: Yes I want to count up to the next empty row, but i don't want to use `isEmpty()`. I'd like to make it work with `Rows.Count`.

Comment: Actually ``cpt2 = wbEmployees.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` works perfectly. And  `Set wbEmployees = GetObject(pathEmployees)` works perfectly too as

Comment: Yes, sorry `GetObject` uses workbook full name, not name. I will delete my comment.